# Selecting nested locations in SPARQL

Tags: nested, sparql, rdf

I'm using the below demonstration:

```
SELECT ?performer ?prefLabel ?date ?location WHERE    
{    
?art rdf:type etree:Concert.    
?art rdf:type mo:Performance.    
?art mo:performer ?performer.    
?art skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel.    
?art etree:date ?date.    
?art event:place ?location.    
}     
LIMIT 2
```

However I also wish to select the values of a named attribute '?place', for which there is a value contained in each entry of '?location', how do I adjust my query to do this?

Comment: I assume that you did not really understand the concept of SPARQL. Otherwise you would know that it's simply adding another triple pattern using the object variable of an existing triple pattern as subject. think about graphs and it's edges that you want to match by patterns. That's the idea of SPARQL

Comment: I think it was more a syntactic issue, but thank-you, I will brush up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what you mean in this phrase:

> named attribute '?place', for which there is a value contained in each
>   entry of '?location'

I guess you are looking for something like [this](http://etree.linkedmusic.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=++++PREFIX+mo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fontology%2Fmo%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+skos%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+etree%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fetree.linkedmusic.org%2Fvocab%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+event%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2FNET%2Fc4dm%2Fevent.owl%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++++SELECT+%3Fperformer+%3FprefLabel+%3Fdate+%3Flocation+%3Fplace+WHERE+%0D%0A++++%7B++++%0D%0A++++++++%3Fart+a+etree%3AConcert%2C+mo%3APerformance+%3B+++%0D%0A+++++++++++++mo%3Aperformer+%3Fperformer+%3B++++%0D%0A+++++++++++++skos%3AprefLabel+%3FprefLabel+%3B++++%0D%0A+++++++++++++etree%3Adate+%3Fdate+%3B++++%0D%0A+++++++++++++event%3Aplace+%3Flocation+.+%0D%0A++++++++%3Flocation+etree%3Alocation+%3Fplace+.+++%0D%0A++++%7D+limit+2%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on):

```sql
PREFIX mo: <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX etree: <http://etree.linkedmusic.org/vocab/>
PREFIX event: <http://purl.org/NET/c4dm/event.owl#>

SELECT ?performer ?prefLabel ?date ?location ?place WHERE 
{    
    ?art a etree:Concert, mo:Performance ;   
         mo:performer ?performer ;    
         skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel ;    
         etree:date ?date ;    
         event:place ?location . 
    ?location etree:location ?place .   
} LIMIT 2
```